# Bash grep regular expression correction

Tags: bash, grep

Lines I search for in a text look like this one:

```
@Article{Courtois:1971:readers,
```

So I need to filter the wrong written ones (right: after `@*letters*{` it should start with a name, which consist only letters and "-", then follows an ":", then a year or "xxxx", then again an ":", and then a line of letters, digits and "-" of some length and ends with a ","), so I try to do it this way:

```
grep --color -E -n '^@' literatur.bib |
grep -E -P -v '([A-z]|-)+:([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|xxxx):([A-z][0-9]|-)+'
```

What is wrong?

There is no output at all, --color and -P were removed. It is stands now "The end of the specified interval is not valid"

Comment: At the very minimum you can't combine `-E` and `-P` as they select different regex dialects. You actually don't seem to use any `-P` features here, and the option is not properly portable; so I suggest you drop that. (You don't reveal which actual problem you are having; I suspect it is unrelated to this issue.)

Comment: Mixing in `--color` seems wrong as well; now you need the second `grep` to cope correctly with any color control codes.

Comment: Probably [edit] this to show some example output which differs from what you expected, and explain why you expected something else.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't seem to actually look for a comma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

- `@*letters*{`
- name - letters **and** `-`
- follows an `:`
- year `xxxx`
- again an `:`
- a line of letters, digits and `-` (? a "line" is the whole thing)
- ends with a `,`

That would be:

```
grep '^@[a-zA-Z]\+{[a-zA-Z-]\+:[1-9][0-9]\{3\}:[a-zA-Z-]\+,'
```

Some notes except those in the comments:

- Don't use `[A-z]`, it's something strange, in [ascii encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/) that would be same as letters `A-Z` with characters `[\]^_` and backtick ` and then letters `a-z`. I don't think you want to allow those special characters in your match. And that is in ascii encoding, so different characters in different encodings may be between `Z` and `a`. Use `[a-zA-Z]` to mean all the letters. Or use `[:alpha:]` character class.
- That is also why `[A-z]` is giving an error `grep: Invalid range end` in extended regex. `z` can't end the range of `A`. You meant `[A-Za-z]`.
- `([A-z]|-)+` in perl regex means one or more the **same** of letters `A-Z` **or** `-`. So it would match ex. `------` or `AAAAA` or `^^^^^^^`. It would **not** match ex. `Blabla` (as a whole, it would match first letter only), because the letters meant to be **the same**. I guess you meant: `[A-Za-z-]+`.
- `([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|xxxx)` in extended regex means a 4 digits **or** exactly 4 characters `x`.
- [Regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/) and other games available on the web are great resources to learn regexes with fun and very fast.
- `([A-z][0-9]|-)+` in extended regex means the same set of `[A-z]` followed by `[0-9]` one or more times or `-` one or more times. It would match ex. `A9A9A9` or `b8b8` or `-----`. It would not match ex. `A9b8` or `Bla`.  I guess you meant `[A-Za-z0-9-]+`.

Tested with:

```
cat <<EOF |
@Article{Courtois:1971:readers,
@Misc{Smith:1997:stack_smashing_unix,
EOF
grep '^@[a-zA-Z]\+{[a-zA-Z-]\+:[1-9][0-9]\{3\}:[a-zA-Z-]\+,'
```

[outputs on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/GrouchyKeenScience):

```
@Article{Courtois:1971:readers,
```

Comment: Now it gives me all the lines, starting with "@", wrong ones as well

Comment: Then edit your question, give more examples, and explain better and exactly what you want. Provide a sample input with enough examples to cover all the edge cases and sample output for the input provided. I understood you want these lines. I don't understand - which ones are "wrong"?

Comment: wrong means for example lines, where are "_" beside the letters given, which doesn't match the requirements

Comment: Please try not to describe with "words" what you want if you can, instead please _show_ what you want. It's really really really easier to explain using examples then words. `_` beside which letters? Which requirements? Match what exactly?

Comment: There is some amount of lines starting with "@" in the text, so I need to filter all of them first, and than I need to filter out all the right written lines and see the wrong ones...

Comment: All the requirements are written in the question, example as well... Wrong one is for example this one: 
@Misc{Smith:1997:stack_smashing_unix,

Comment: I don't understand. You want _both_ the "right" and "wring" lines? (where "right" and "wrong" is understood as matching the regex or not). The line you showed would be excluded by the regex in my answer.

Comment: I need to see the wrong ones on the screen, but firstly I have to filter out all the lines which doesn't begin with "@". Otherwise I will get not only the wrong lines, but all the other lines as well. That is why I use -v in the second pipe...

Comment: Practically I need the inverse result of your test... I guess something goes wrong in the pipe connection, because the first part obviously works (I see all the lines beginning with "@"), but in doesn't sort out the right ones (second part) grep -n '^@' literatur.bib | grep -E -v '^@[a-zA-Z]\+{[a-zA-Z-]\+:[1-9][0-9]\{3\}:[a-zA-Z-]\+,'